# sequence$\frac{A}{B}\rightarrow \alpha\neq 0$, show if A is summable, B is summable.

Tags: real-analysis

If sequence$\frac{A}{B}\rightarrow \alpha\neq 0$, show if A is summable, B is summable.

I was trying to use contrapositive of the statement suppsoe A converges to L and B to M.$If M\neq 0 then \frac{A}{B}\rightarrow \frac{L}{M}$

But it didn't work out well since we do not know if B has a limit or not. How do I show B converges?

Comment: I don't think the problem statement makes sense.  Where did the problem come from?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense. I mean B could also go to zero so it will make sense. But I just try to prove B converges first. Then use contradiction to show that B has to go to zero.

Comment: I just changed the problem .... sorry